# Unable to Customize SharePoint 2013 Discussion Board

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, discussion-board, view

We are trying to customize SharePoint 2013 Discussion Board app and are unable to modify existing Flat, Subject, and Threaded views or create new views.  Following are the error messages we are getting:

Error message when creating new views based on view types Subject, Flat, or Threaded:

> TypeError: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or
>   undefined

Note that when creating the view no options are available (only option to name and make default are available).  The view created after display of this error message does not have any Columns, Sort, Filter or other properties defined.  Manually defining these properties does not make the view function as desired (Flat view is not flat).

Error message when editing existing default views Subject, Flat, or Threaded:

> Cannot complete this action. Please try again. Troubleshoot issues
>   with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Note that this is nothing to troubleshoot or error number provided.  The URL shows `/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001`.  Also, the edit screen does not show any view property to change.

Note that both ability to edit existing views and create new views work in SharePoint 2010.  This issue is with SharePoint 2013.  Please guide to resolve this.  View in other apps can be edited.  This issue is only with the Discussion Board app.

Comment: Same problem here ... any news on that?

Answer (score 7):

If you have SharePoint designer, open the view with it and change the settings "read only" to FALSE and then you will be able to modify the views from SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/06/unable-to-edit-default-discussion-board.html) shows some images of using SharePoint Designer to set the read-only property.

Answer (score 0):

Go to List Settings(Discussion List) -> Under Views -> Click on Threaded View -> It will navigate to the respective Edit view: Check the option `Make as Default view`

After click ok, you can see the view option in Edit option

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with SharePoint Discussion Board, you would have known this that it doesn't allow you to edit the view in GUI.

Simply go to designer and change the ReadOnly = TRUE to ReadOnly = False.

You can also refer to my article on the same ([How to modify the existing Flat/Subject/Threaded View in Discussion Board of SharePoint 2013](http://sabinatechdiary.blogspot.in/2015/08/how-to-modify-existing.html))

Thanks

Sabby